# mysql: issue with the demonstration of sql injection

Tags: mysql

according to this tutorial:http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php
Below codes will demonstrate SQL Injection:

```php
<?php
// a good user's name
$name = "timmy"; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '$name'";
echo "Normal: " . $query . "<br />";

// user input that uses SQL Injection
$name_bad = "' OR 1'"; 

// our MySQL query builder, however, not a very safe one
$query_bad = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '$name_bad'";

// display what the new query will look like, with injection
echo "Injection: " . $query_bad;
```

In front end, it shows:
`Injection: SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '' OR 1''`

So I just did a test, in phpmyadmin->sql, I run below codes:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname = '' OR 1''`

And it shows:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Qustion:

supposed it will show every single entry in the `"users"` table, but not, why? if I want to demonstrate sql injection, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more typical SQL injection would be: `$name_bad = "' OR 1=1 -- ";`. This would lead to the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '' OR 1=1 -- '
```

Comment: well, I tried `SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname = '' OR 1=1 --'`, it still shows: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1`  While `SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE fname = 'Jim'` works

Comment: Per the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html), comments require whitespace after the `--`. Try `$name_bad = "' OR 1=1 -- ";`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname = '' OR 1 = 1
```

is likely what they meant

edit just looked

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE fname = '' OR 1
```

1 evaluates to true, so just remove the '' after it

also that link is way out of date, Look at mysqli or pdo instead